# How to show url that contains a pdf and show it embedded in a Webview Android Java

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I'm trying to show a url that contains a pdf. I want to show it embedded in a webview, but it is generating an error and I can not find the solution, I do not know if it is from the google viewer. Please, if anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

```
public class PoliticaTratamientoDatos extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ImageView imgBotonVolver;
    private WebView webViewPolitica;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_politica_tratamiento_datos);
        imgBotonVolver = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBotonVolver);
        imgBotonVolver.setOnClickListener(this);

        webViewPolitica = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPolitica);
        webViewPolitica.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        String pdf = "https://www.bancoagrario.gov.co/canales/Seguridad/Documents/DocTratamientoDatosPersonales.pdf";
        webViewPolitica.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdf);
        //webViewPolitica.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdf + "&embedded=true");
    }
}
```

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewPolitica"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the error in my webview is:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>

<script>

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var dosl7_common;

window["bobcmn"] = "1111101010101020000000220000000520000000022a40ac4f200000096300000000300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https200000000200000000";

window.RaP=!!window.RaP;try{(function(){try{var ll,Ll,Ol=1,Sl=1,Il=1;for(var Jl=0;Jl<Ll;++Jl)Ol+=2,Sl+=2,Il+=3;ll=Ol+Sl+Il;window.z_===ll&&(window.z_=++ll)}catch(lL){window.z_=ll}var zL=!0;function ZL(l){l&&(zL=!1,document.cookie="brav=ad");return zL}function iL(){}ZL(window[iL.name]===iL);ZL("function"!==typeof ie9rgb4);ZL(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&!/x3d/.test(function(){return"'x3'+'d';"}));
var jL=window.attachEvent||/mobi/i.test(window["\x6e\x61vi\x67a\x74\x6f\x72"]["\x75\x73e\x72A\x67\x65\x6et"]),JL=+new Date+6E5,_o,Io,Jo=setTimeout,lO=jL?3E4:6E3;function LO(){if(!document.querySelector)return!0;var l=+new Date,z=l>JL;if(z)return ZL(!1);z=Io&&_o+lO<l;z=ZL(z);_o=l;Io||(Io=!0,Jo(function(){Io=!1},1));return z}LO();var OO=[17795081,27611931586,1558153217];
function zO(l){l="string"===typeof l?l:l.toString(36);var z=window[l];if(!z.toString)return;var S=""+z;window[l]=function(l,S){Io=!1;return z(l,S)};window[l].toString=function(){return S}}for(var sO=0;sO<OO.length;++sO)zO(OO[sO]);ZL(!1!==window.RaP);
(function SO(){if(!LO())return;var z=!1;function S(z){for(var s=0;z--;)s+=_(document.documentElement,null);return s}function _(z,s){var S="vi";s=s||new I;return _l(z,function(z){z.setAttribute("data-"+S,s.ol());return _(z,s)},null)}function I(){this._j=1;this.sj=0;this.zS=this._j;this.c=null;this.ol=function(){this.c=this.sj+this.zS;if(!isFinite(this.c))return this.reset(),this.ol();this.sj=this.zS;this.zS=this.c;this.c=null;return this.zS};this.reset=function(){this._j++;this.sj=0;this.zS=this._j}}
var J=!1;function s(z,s){if(!LO())return;var S=document.createElement(z);s=s||document.body;s.appendChild(S);S&&S.style&&(S.style.display="none");LO()}function zl(s,S){if(!LO())return;S=S||s;var _="|";function I(z){z=z.split(_);var s=[];for(var S=0;S<z.length;++S){var J="",ol=z[S].split(",");for(var zl=0;zl<ol.length;++zl)J+=ol[zl][zl];s.push(J)}return s}var zl=0,_l="datalist,details,embed,figure,hrimg,strong,article,formaddress|audio,blockquote,area,source,input|canvas,form,link,tbase,option,details,article";
_l.split(_);_l=I(_l);_l=new RegExp(_l.join(_),"g");while(_l.exec(s))_l=new RegExp((""+new Date)[8],"g"),z&&(J=LO()),++zl;return LO()?S(zl&&1):void 0}function _l(z,S,_){if(!LO())return;(_=_||J)&&s("div",z);z=z.children;var I=0;for(var zl in z){_=z[zl];try{_ instanceof HTMLElement&&(S(_),++I)}catch(_l){}}return LO()?I:void 0}zl(SO,S);LO()})();var _O=95;window.ij={Jj:"081b250c89017800dc2d9278ef592d39fb30f82160d2a2a82186935b699c223b6e87475b486458e48c010d7b7b4ad500aa1e0c7c1d561dc7fb109bde286064f19d9e584f8837a118e94e111b8d72348c7c116746bbd2a93704e9a956b7ea023075ba10d3e0516cc2be6d3cc8f122314e647d2cc4907d35109c3cb105c6360463"};function L(l){return 947>l}
function O(l){var z=arguments.length,S=[];for(var _=1;_<z;++_)S.push(arguments[_]-l);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,S)}function Z(l,z){l+=z;return l.toString(36)}(function iO(z){return z?0:iO(z)*iO(z)})(LO());})();}catch(x){document.cookie='brav=oex'+x;}finally{ie9rgb4=void(0);};function ie9rgb4(a,b){return a>>b>>0};

})();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/08d7da57a9ab2000f6d4855c247e06d6be4b102a7e42062d10476ec486a8a0201e92a422e6e2460b?type=7"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, please help!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your .pdf come from Google Docs, and Google is redirecting you to another URL.</s>

Use below code for the `WebView`:

```
webViewPolitica.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

The [link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.bancoagrario.gov.co/canales/Seguridad/Documents/DocTratamientoDatosPersonales.pdf) sometimes not worked in my browser, so I believe the the .pdf link cause the problem. Sometimes mybrowser occur ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when open [it](https://www.bancoagrario.gov.co/canales/Seguridad/Documents/DocTratamientoDatosPersonales.pdf).

Hope this help you.

Comment: Have you checked my edited answer? It seems it is the URL connection problem

Comment: I suggest you download the pdf file and load it from local resources